# Matriz alfanúmerica

Tags: c, matrices

Quiero realizar un programa en donde pueda trabajar con matrices alfanuméricas y realizarle diferentes operaciones. Sólo necesito saber cómo puedo introducir los datos. Como por ejemplo una matriz;

|0 A B 0|

|0 0 0 C|

|E A 0 0|

|0 0 A L|

Comment: Ariel, ¿podrías por favor aportar lo que has hecho hasta ahora con el código?

Answer (score 0):

*...Sólo necesito saber cómo puedo introducir los datos...*

Podria usar un `char[]` e introducir los datos digamos estos |0 A B 0|.

*...Quiero realizar un programa en donde pueda trabajar con matrices alfanuméricas y realizarle diferentes operaciones...*

eso de las operaciones dependera de como quiera que trabaje esa parte, pero puede usar [`isalnum`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalnum/) por ejemplo para saber si se encuentra con un numero o un letra este es un ejemplo que puede ver en el link que le deje:

```
/* isalnum example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main ()
{
  int i;
  char str[]="c3po...";
  i=0;
  while (isalnum(str[i])) i++;
  printf ("The first %d characters are alphanumeric.\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Tambien puede echar un vistazo a:

- [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) Comprueba si "c" es una letra del alfabeto.
- [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) Comprueba si "c" es un carácter dígito decimal.