# ¿Cómo evitar un error cuando se espera un número como input y el usuario digita una letra? C++

Tags: c++

```
void getPiezas(int* piezas,int* f2){
    cout << "Digite cantidad de piezas a procesar\n";
    cin >> *piezas;
    ...
}
```

si el usuario digita una letra en vez de un número entero o si digita un `double` en lugar de un `int`. Cómo debo abordar el código?

Comment: ajuste del comantario anterior: con los datos que te pasa el usuario comprobar que estos son los esperados si es una letra le pides que vuelva a introducir el dato, si es un double lo mismo o puedes hacer un cast para este caso, basicamente es no dejar avanzar al usuario hasta que los datos no sean los esperados, existen muchos ejemplos de codigo que manejan esta situacion con un while o similar.Por otro lado en esta res. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65235/matriz-alfan%C3%BAmerica/65237#65237 para comprobar si es digito ect al final de la respu. Saludos

Answer (score 5):

Cuando se produce un error en la lectura de un dato, por ejemplo que se espere recibir un entero y el usuario introduzca una letra, se activan los *flags* de error de `std::cin` y, lo que es igualmente importante, las siguientes lecturas no se van a realizar. Se puede comprobar con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
  int var;
  std::string texto;

  std::cin >> var >> texto;
  std::cout << '-' << texto << '-';
}
```

Si únicamente se introduce un texto, por ejemplo `asdf`, el programa sacará por pantalla `--`. Esto se produce porque al fallar la lectura del entero, `std::cin` activa el bit de error y se bloquea. Para poder seguir utilizando el *stream* es necesario resetear los bits de error:

```
int main()
{
  std::string texto;
  int var;
  std::cin >> var;

  if( !std::cin.good() )
    std::cin.clear();

  std::cin >> texto;
  std::cout << '-' << texto << '-';
}
```

Si ahora se repite la entrada `asdf` el programa imprimirá `-asdf-` lo que indica que ante una lectura errónea el *stream* no descarta ningún dato... como lo normal es que si un dato no es válido el programa se quede esperando a que se introduzca uno válido es necesario descartar los datos erróneos del *buffer* de entrada y esto se consige con el método `ignore()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int var;

  while( true )
  {
    std::cin >> var;
    if( !std::cin.good() )
    {
      std::cout << "ERROR\n";
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    else
      break;
  }

  std::cout << var;
}
```

`numeric_limits` es una plantilla que permite obtener el rango de valores admitido por un tipo de dato dado (`int`, `short`, `long long`, ...). En el caso de los alias (`std::size`, `std::streamsize`, ...) es el compilador el que hace la conversión al tipo nativo correspondiente.

Esto se podría embeber facilmente en una función para ello se podría hacer de muchas maneras posibles... tirando por lo sencillo la función podría cumplir la siguiente premisa: "retorna un booleano que indica si la lectura se ha realizado correctamente o no. Recibe además un entero por referencia que únicamente se actualiza cuando la lectura es correcta":

```
bool ReadInt(int& valor)
{
  std::cin >> valor;

  bool ok = std::cin.good();

  if( !ok )
  {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
  }

  return ok;
}
```

Vamos a probar la función:

```
int main()
{
  int var;

  while( true )
  {
    if( !ReadInt(var) )
      std::cout << "ERROR\n";
    else
      break;
  }

  std::cout << var;
}
```

---

**Edito**

Para tratar el tema de los decimales se puede hacer lo siguiente: Una vez leído el dato se verifican que los flags de error no se han activado. Entonces se entenderá que el dato leído es correcto si se produce cualquiera de las siguientes circunstancias:

- En el buffer de entrada encontramos un salto de línea
- En el buffer de entrada encontramos un espacio

Aplicando esto a la función anterior nos quedaría así:

```
bool ReadInt(int& valor)
{
  std::cin >> valor;

  bool ok = std::cin.good();

  if( ok )
  {
    char c = static_cast<char>(std::cin.peek());
    ok = (c == '\n' || c == ' ' );
  }

  if( !ok )
  {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
  }

  return ok;
}
```

Comment: Agradezco la respuestas de todos. @eferion la tuya me es de mucha ayuda, es la que mejor adapto a mi código, sin embargo aun no se como usar numeric_limits para corregir el error si se ingresa un double. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @R.Ramirez respuesta editada

Answer (score 3):

Depende de lo que entiendas por error ¡ya lo estás evitando!.

#### ¿Dónde está el error?

Por defecto, cuando a un objeto de la familia [`std::basic_istream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) (como `std::cin`) le das a leer algo diferente a la entrada que le proporcionas, no lanza un error. Dependiendo de la versión del estándar de C++ que tu compilador siga, supongamos este código:

```
int a = 11111;
int b = 22222;

std::cout << "Pon un valor numérico: ";
std::cin >> a;

std::cout << "Pon un valor numérico: ";
std::cin >> b;

std::cout << "El valor a es: " << a << '\n'
          << "El valor b es: " << b << '\n';
```

Para estos datos de entrada:

> ```
> Pon un valor numérico: 1
> Pon un valor numérico: patata
> ```

Se comportará de la siguiente manera:

- En estándares previos a C++11, cuando una lectura con formato falla, el dato de entrada permanece inalterado.
- En estándares posteriores a C++11, cuando una lectura con formato falla, el dato de entrada obtiene el valor `0`.

Así pues, según el estándar que siga tu compilador obtendrás estas salidas:

`Anterior a C++11`

> ```
>  El valor a es: 1
>  El valor b es: 22222
> ```

`C++11 o superior`

> ```
>  El valor a es: 1
>  El valor b es: 0
> ```

#### No hay error a la vista, pero podemos buscarlo.

Sin embargo, en ambos casos, dado que se habrá producido una lectura de datos incorrecta el flujo de datos establecerá la [bandera de fallos](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) a valor verdadero, puedes consultar esta bandera con la función [`std::basic_ios::fail`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail):

```
int leer_valor()
{
    int resultado;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Pon un valor numérico: ";
        std::cin >> resultado;

        if (!std::cin.fail())
            return resultado;

        std::cout << "Algo ha fallado al leer\n";
        std::cin.clear();
    }
}

int a = leer_valor();
int b = leer_valor();

std::cout << "El valor a es: " << a << '\n'
          << "El valor b es: " << b << '\n';
```

En el ejemplo, la función `leer_valor` pediría infinitamente valores al usuario hasta que la lectura de `std::cin` sea correcta. Es importante borrar la bandera de fallo con [`std::basic_ios::clear`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) porque si no, las lecturas posteriores fallarían incluso siendo correctas.

#### ¿Quieres errores? ¡Tendrás errores!

Por defecto, cuando a un objeto de la familia [`std::basic_istream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) (como `std::cin`) le das a leer algo diferente a la entrada que le proporcionas, no lanza un error pero podemos configurarlo para que lance excepciones en caso de lectura errónea usando la función [`std::basic_ios::exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions):

```
int a = 11111;
int b = 22222;
std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);

try
{
    std::cout << "Pon un valor numérico: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "Pon un valor numérico: ";
    std::cin >> b;
}
catch (std::ios_base::failure &error)
{
    std::cout << "Algo ha pasado al leer!";
}

std::cout << "El valor a es: " << a << '\n'
          << "El valor b es: " << b << '\n';
```

Aunque aparentemente esta opción no es muy popular.

#### ¿Y si se digita un `double`?.

Leer un `double` sobre un entero usando la entrada estándar no producirá ningún error, ni establecerá las banderas de fallo ni lanzará excepciones si lo configuras para ello. Simplemente [asignará la parte entera](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8fP082qfyzBjzgte) del número de la entrada a la variable `int` proporcionada. Lo cuál no me parece muy problemático. Pero si realmente lo necesitas lo más adecuado sería leer la entrada como **texto** y comprobar que todos los caracteres sean numéricos:

```
int leer_valor()
{
    std::string lectura;
    std::locale l("");

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Pon un valor numérico: ";
        std::cin >> lectura;

        if (std::all_of(lectura.cbegin(), lectura.cend(), [&l](auto v) { return std::isdigit(v, l); }))
            return std::stoi(resultado);

        std::cout << "Algo ha fallado al leer\n";
    }
}

int a = leer_valor();
int b = leer_valor();

std::cout << "El valor a es: " << a << '\n'
          << "El valor b es: " << b << '\n';
```

El ejemplo anterior usa el algoritmo que comprueba que todos los datos de una colección cumplan con una función, en este caso todos los datos de la cadena leída deben cumplir con [`std::isdigit`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isdigit) así que valores alfabéticos o valores decimales no pasarán el filtro. Hay que tener en cuenta que salvo que suceda algo extraño, la lectura desde consola a una variable de texto no fallará nunca.

#### Conclusión.

Si el usuario digita una letra en vez de un número entero puedes controlarlo mediante la lectura de las banderas de error pero si digita un `double` en lugar de un `int` es necesario guardar en una variable de texto y analizarla.

Comment: +1 por el try catch

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, creo que lo que quieres no es que piezas sea un array. Me baso en que en la salida por consola pones "cantidad de piezas", y si es solo **una** la cantidad que necesitas, la declaración de la función tendría que modificarse.

```
void getPiezas(int piezas,int* f2){...}
```

Si lo que querías era pasar `piezas` por referencia para poder modificar su valor sería:

```
void getPiezas(int& piezas,int* f2){...}
```

En cuanto a la lectura de datos, puedes incluir ésta en un bucle hasta que no se cumplan una serie de condiciones. Por ejemplo, leer los datos en forma de `string` y analizar cada uno de los caracteres de la cadena posteriormente en una funcion auxiliar.

```
void getPiezas(int& piezas, int* f2){
    std::string aux ;

    std::cout << "Digite cantidad de piezas a procesar\n";
    std::cin >> aux;

    while(!esEntero(aux)){
        std::cout << "El número de piezas debe ser un entero\n";
        std::cout << "Digite cantidad de piezas a procesar\n";
        std::cin >> aux;
    }

    piezas = stoi(aux) ;
}
```

Dichas condiciones las puedes realizar en una función booleana que te indique si se trata de un entero o no. En este caso se ha ido examinando cada caracter de la cadena para saber si se trata cada uno de ellos de un decimal. En el momento que haya alguno que no lo sea, se sale del bucle y devuelve `false`.

```
bool esEntero(const std::string& piezas){
    bool resultado = true ;
    for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < piezas.size() && resultado ; i++)
        if(std::isdigit(piezas[i]) == 0)
            resultado = false ;

    return resultado ;
}
```

Comment: No pasa nada, es bueno plantear todas estas cosas porque se aprende mucho. Gracias @eferion